# Why is my transition not working on "leave"?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-transitions

I have a global `confirmModal.vue` which looks like this:

```js
<template>
  <Transition
    appear
    enter-from-class="opacity-0"
    enter-to-class="opacity-100"
    leave-from-class="opacity-100"
    leave-to-class="opacity-0"
  >
    <div
      @click="$emit('cancel')"
      class="bg-black/50 z-50 fixed inset-0 flex justify-center items-center transition duration-300 ease-in-out p-8 cursor-pointer"
    >
      <Transition appear enter-from-class="scale-50" enter-to-class="scale-100">
        <div
          @click.stop
          class="flex flex-col gap-4 shadow-2xl p-8 rounded min-w-[300px] max-w-[480px] bg-lf-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out cursor-auto"
        >
          <h3 class="font-medium text-2xl">{{ title }}</h3>
          <p>{{ text }}</p>

          <div class="flex justify-end gap-2">
            <Button @click="$emit('cancel')" variant="white">Annuler</Button>
            <Button @click="$emit('confirm')">Supprimer</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Transition>
    </div>
  </Transition>
</template>
```

The first transition adds a fade in effect to the backdrop while the nested transition adds a smooth apparition effect for the modal itself.

It works fine but what I don't understand is that when I close the modal, the `leave` part of the transition does not trigger at all.

This is what the component calling this modal looks like:

```js
<ConfirmModal
  v-if="showConfirmModal"
  title="Suppression"
  text="Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet article ?"
  @cancel="handleHideConfirmModal"
  @confirm="handleConfirmAction"
/>
```

Here's a gif of what it's currently looks like:

[image]

EDIT: I achieved the wanted result by wrapping `ConfirmModal.vue` with `Transition` from the parent component, like this:

```js
    <Transition
      enter-from-class="opacity-0"
      enter-to-class="opacity-100"
      leave-from-class="opacity-100"
      leave-to-class="opacity-0"
    >
      <ConfirmModal
        v-if="showConfirmModal"
        title="Suppression"
        text="Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet article ?"
        @cancel="handleHideConfirmModal"
      />
    </Transition>
```

I don't understand why I have to do this and why in [this exemple](https://codepen.io/tahazsh/pen/mvKjbq) the person doesn't need to do that though, they use `Transition` from inside the child component and the transition works fine

It's also not ideal because every time I use this component I will have to think to wrap it inside this transition for it to fully work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably caused by the use of different versions of Vue.

Your question is tagged `vuejs3`, so you are very likely using Vue 3, but, in the example you [linked](https://codepen.io/tahazsh/pen/mvKjbq), vue version `2.6.4` is being used.

In vue 3, at least, you must use the directives `v-if` or `v-show` in the root element inside the `Transition` component for it to trigger the changes whenever the root component inside appears and disappears.

you can read more about transitions [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#the-transition-component)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes I'm using Vue 3. I guess you're right, I haven't thought about the difference between the versions. I made it to fully works with the Vue 3 way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `:key="$route.fullPath"`, it binds the route's full path as the key, ensuring that a route change triggers the transition with the leave-active class.
Now, when you navigate between routes, the leaving component will have the leave-active class applied, and you should see the transition effect as defined in your CSS.